# How to press pause key in python

Tags: python, keyboard, pyautogui

I am creating a pyautogui automation that connect to a W3270 terminal (really old :))
this terminal is expecting pause key to be pressed,
Apart pyautogui, I also tried Keyboard library, but i am unable to send pause

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import constants as const

locateOnScreen(const.IPAIRE_TERMINAL_CONNECTED)

command = '/FOR SIGNON'
pause = '\u0019'
pyautogui.write(command)
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.send('pause')
```

Am I suppose to use keyboard to simulate 'pause' button?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using pynput

```
import pyautogui
import constants as const
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

locateOnScreen(const.IPAIRE_TERMINAL_CONNECTED)

command = '/FOR SIGNON'
pyautogui.write(command)
time.sleep(1)
keyboard = Controller()
keyboard.press(Key.pause)
keyboard.release(Key.pause)
```